# Sorting an unsorted array using 3 stacks in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, stack

Here is the question I am trying to answer

Construct a new sorting algorithm which uses ONLY three stacks, labelled A, B, and C, a
single “double” variable called x, and any auxiliary variables such as loop counters. Your
algorithm assumes that stack A contains a collection of UNSORTED data, and by the end
of your algorithm, one of the stacks will contain the data sorted in increasing order.

I am trying to figure out the algorithm for it in Java, but I can't figure it out for the life of me! Can you help?!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It will be easier to help you if we know where you got stuck

Comment: "Insertion Sort", "Selection Sort", and "Bubble Sort" are common sorting algorithms that are easy to implement with 3 stacks.  Google 'em

Comment: I have an implementation I could use, however I am confused about the use of the "double" variable called x

Comment: In my answer I took the double value as a double array but I assume you might want to ask whoever is teaching you what it means.

Comment: Sounds like the Tower of Hanoi game

Comment: With stacks I would probably use a multiway merge sort, tuned for three stacks.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a fast poly phase merge sort code example in Java. it's fairly fast, sorting 16 million random doubles in about 4 seconds on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple program to take values from an array and then print them to a command console would be.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackSort
{
    static Stack<Double> A = new Stack<Double>();

    public void createStackA()
    {
        double[] x = {-10,5, 2, 1, 9, 0, 10};
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            A.push(x[i]);
        }
    }

    public void sortStackA(Stack<Double> C)
    {
        Stack<Double> B = new Stack<Double>();

        while(!C.isEmpty())
        {
            double s1 = (double) C.pop();

            while(!B.isEmpty() && (B.peek() > s1))
            {
                C.push(B.pop());
            }
            B.push(s1);
        }

        System.out.println(B);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StackSort sS = new StackSort();
        sS.createStackA();
        sS.sortStackA(A);
    }
}
```

Comment: The example code is for a 2 stack sort. Since the question is about a 3 stack sort, I"m wondering if the goal is to implement some form of bottom up merge sort.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a bonus for doing a faster sort, with 3 stacks you can implement a bottom up merge sort O(n log(n)). As pointed out by greybeard, a poly phase bottom up merge sort (a method oriented towards tape drives or other sequential devices), should be the fastest 3 stack sort.

A simpler merge sort would move every run (initial size == 1) from A to B and C, in an alternating pattern, even runs to B, odd runs to C, then 2 way merge B and C back to A, double run size, repeat until run size >= stack size. Poly phase eliminates the move / split steps, except for an initial distribute step that moves some of the elements from A to B and C.

Setting up the initial descending / ascending state (reverses the sense of a compare), and tracking when the run size on a stack changes (+1 or -1) due to dummy elements was a bit tricky. I used a table of 47 Fibonacci integers for initial distribution setup (handles stack size up to 1/2 billion elements). Stack size is known at the start, but this could be generated by doing a single copy (copy order doesn't matter since initial run size is 1).

Initial distribution for n elements: Assume that fib(m+1) > n > fib(m). n-fib(m) elements are moved to B. fib(m+1)-n elements are moved to C. n-fib(m) elements from A and B are merged (pushed) to C. After the first merge, C ends up with n-fib(m) runs of size 2, and fib(m+1)-n runs of size 1 = fib(m-1) runs. B is emptied. A ends up with (n) - (fib(m+1)-n) - 2(n-fib(m)) = 2 fib(m) - fib(m+1) = fib(m) - fib(m-1) = fib(m-2) runs of size 1. In the case that n = fib(m), then fib(m-1) elements are moved to B, leaving fib(m-2) elements in A.

Wiki article also describes a similar situation to the 3 stack sort with tape drives written forward and read backwards, but doesn't mention the details of how to distribute dummy runs (runs of size 0) at the start, but this was probably included in that 55 year old publication mentioned by greybeard.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort

I wrote a C++ example, but since the question asked for Java (example code below), I'll provide a link to a zip for the C++ example. Instead of a stack class, the C++ example uses arrays with a stack pointer for each array (ppmrg3s.cpp). The zip also has a regular poly phase merge sort using arrays (ppmrg.cpp).

http://rcgldr.net/misc/ppmrg.zip

Example java code. On my system, Intel 2600K, 3.4ghz, Win 7 64 bit, it sorts 16 million doubles in about 4 seconds.

```
public class ppmrg3s {
    static final int[] FIBTBL =
   {         0,         1,         1,         2,         3,         5,
             8,        13,        21,        34,        55,        89,
           144,       233,       377,       610,       987,      1597,
          2584,      4181,      6765,     10946,     17711,     28657,
         46368,     75025,    121393,    196418,    317811,    514229,
        832040,   1346269,   2178309,   3524578,   5702887,   9227465,
      14930352,  24157817,  39088169,  63245986, 102334155, 165580141,
     267914296, 433494437, 701408733,1134903170,1836311903};

    // return index of largest fib() <= n
    static int flfib(int n)
    {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = 47;
        while((hi - lo) > 1){
            int i = (lo + hi)/2;
            if(n < FIBTBL[i]){
                hi = i;
                continue;
            }
            if(n > FIBTBL[i]){
                lo = i;
                continue;
            }
            return i;
        }
        return lo;
    }

    // poly phase merge sort using 3 stacks
    static void ppmrg3s(dstack a, dstack b, dstack c)
    {
        if(a.size() < 2)
            return;
        int ars = 1;                        // init run sizes
        int brs = 1;
        int asc = 0;                        // no size change
        int bsc = 0;
        int csc = 0;
        int scv = 0-1;                      // size change value
        boolean dsf;                        // == 1 if descending sequence
        {                                   // block for local variable scope
            int f = flfib(a.size());        // FIBTBL[f] >= size >= FIBTBL[f-1]
            dsf = ((f%3) == 0);             // init compare flag
            if(FIBTBL[f] == a.size()){      // if exact fibonacci size,
                for (int i = 0; i < FIBTBL[f - 1]; i++) { //  move to b
                    b.push(a.pop());
                }
            } else {                        // else move to b, c
                // update compare flag
                dsf ^= 1 == ((a.size() - FIBTBL[f]) & 1);
                // i = excess run count
                int i = a.size() - FIBTBL[f];
                // j = dummy run count
                int j = FIBTBL[f + 1] - a.size();
                // move excess elements to b
                do{
                    b.push(a.pop());
                }while(0 != --i);
                // move dummy count elements to c
                do{
                    c.push(a.pop());
                }while(0 != --j);
                csc = c.size();
            }
        }                                   // end block scope
        while(true){                        // start merge pass
            if(asc == a.size()){            // check for size count change
                ars += scv;                 //   (due to dummy run size == 0)
                scv = 0-scv;
                asc = 0;
                csc = c.size();
            }
            if(bsc == b.size()){
                brs += scv;
                scv = 0-scv;
                bsc = 0;
                csc = c.size();
            }
            int arc = ars;                  // init run counters
            int brc = brs;
            while(true){                    // start merge pair of runs
                if(dsf ^ (a.peek() <= b.peek())){
                    c.push(a.pop());        // move a to c
                    if(--arc != 0)          // if not end a
                        continue;           //   continue back to compare
                    do{                     // else move rest of b run to c
                        c.push(b.pop());
                    }while(0 != --brc);
                    break;                  //   and break
                } else {
                    c.push(b.pop());        // move b to c
                    if(0 != --brc)          // if not end b
                        continue;           //   continue back to compare
                    do{                     // else move rest of a run to c
                        c.push(a.pop());
                    }while(0 != --arc);
                    break;                  //   and break
                }
            }                               // end merge pair of runs
            dsf ^= true;                    // toggle compare flag
            if(b.empty()){                  // if end b
                if(a.empty())               //   if end a, done
                    break;
                b.swap(c);                  //   swap b, c
                brs += ars;
                if (0 == asc)
                    bsc = csc;
            } else {                        // else not end b
                if(!a.empty())              //   if not end a
                    continue;               //     continue back to merge pair
                a.swap(c);                  //   swap a, c
                ars += brs;
                if (0 == bsc)
                    asc = csc;
            }
        }
        a.swap(c);                          // return sorted stack in a
    }
```

I created a fast stack class that uses a fixed maximum size array of doubles that includes a swap function member:

```
class dstack{
    double []ar;                            // array
    int sz;                                 // size
    int sp;                                 // stack pointer
    public dstack(int sz){                  // constructor with size
        this.ar = new double[sz];
        this.sz = sz; 
        this.sp = sz;
    }
    public void push(double d){
        this.ar[--sp] = d;
    }
    public double pop(){
        return this.ar[sp++];
    }
    public double peek(){
        return this.ar[sp];
    }
    public boolean empty(){
        return sp == sz;
    }
    public int size(){
        return sz-sp;
    }
    public void swap(dstack othr){
        double []tempar = othr.ar;
        int tempsz = othr.sz;
        int tempsp = othr.sp;
        othr.ar = this.ar;
        othr.sz = this.sz;
        othr.sp = this.sp;
        this.ar = tempar;
        this.sz = tempsz;
        this.sp = tempsp;
    }
}
```

Test program. It uses random integers (nextInt), that get converted to doubles during a.push(...). This made the early debugging easier. For other platforms, or to follow with debug, use a smaller number for NUMELEM, which is the number of elements.

```
    static final int NUMELEM = 16*1024*1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dstack a = new dstack(NUMELEM);
        dstack b = new dstack(NUMELEM);
        dstack c = new dstack(NUMELEM);
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMELEM; i++){
            a.push(r.nextInt(NUMELEM));
        }
        long bgn, end;
        bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ppmrg3s(a, b, c);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double d;
        d = a.pop();
        while(!a.empty()){
            if(d > a.peek()){
                System.out.println("error");
                break;
            }
            d = a.pop();
        }
        System.out.println("milliseconds");
        System.out.println(end-bgn);
    }
```

Comment: (The fun part: it is possible to do a merge sort without copy phases and three stacks, only. According to D.E. Knuth's TAOCP vol. on Sorting and Searching, this was mentioned by R.L. Gilstad in the original publication on polyphase merge - presented exactly 55 years ago.)

Comment: (I'd love to see a readily accessible web resource paying due attention to all the cumbersome details - beware of rather clear, ghastly long - didn't read.) The trick to do a polyphase merge sort with little copying on stacks(read-backwards tape drives) is to have the runs _on each stack_ alternate between ascending and descending (last sentence of the Wikipedia article). Tricky parts are getting the initial distribution right, especially if forming runs of maximal length on the fly, and keeping merging runs of similar length.

Comment: @greybeard - For the write forwards / read backwards tape drive sort, if the tapes are kept streaming and initial run size large enough to compensate for inter-record gap overhead, then merging runs of similar length may not be much of an issue. The code can be a bit less complex since single file mark could indicate end of run, and double file mark end of data. For perfect distribution, the initial pass could read A and write memory sorted runs to B to get a run count, then distribute the runs to A and C, and start poly phase. My answer now has a Java example.

Comment: @greybeard - I did some searching, but so far I haven't found any articles on optimizing the initial distribution to eliminate dummy runs as soon as possible. A general approach for this is to best guess the initial distribution since the run count is unknown in advance, then to copy or merge a portion of the data between the tapes to end up with perfect distribution after the initial merge step.

Answer (score 0):

for a starting hint, check the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) it is a similar approach in that operators (i.e values) are pushed to a stack and popped to another stack (i.e output queue) depending on their relative priority (i.e value)

The algorithm has 3 stacks, a) input queue (lets say A), b) operator stack (lets say B) and c) output queue (lets say C), now try to translate this into an algorithm for sorting

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

1. Move all items from stack A to stack B, store maximum value found in 'x'.
2. Move all items from stack B to stack A, except those with value 'x' determined from previous stem. Move those to C instead.
3. Repeat until both A and B are empty.